# BCM4312 802.11b/g under Fedora 14 - suddenly not working

Tags: fedora, wifi

Suddenly `ifconfig -a` doesn't print out the interface `wlan0` on my Fedora14 notebook..WHY? (it worked before..)

Infos:

```
# dmesg | egrep -i "wireless|wifi|broadcom|bcm4312|10:00.0"
[    0.219841] pci 0000:10:00.0: reg 10: [mem 0xe8000000-0xe8003fff 64bit]
[    0.220074] pci 0000:10:00.0: supports D1 D2
[    1.539203] ata1.00: ACPI cmd c6/00:10:00:00:00:a0 (SET MULTIPLE MODE) succeeded
[    1.543355] ata1.00: ACPI cmd c6/00:10:00:00:00:a0 (SET MULTIPLE MODE) succeeded

# lspci | fgrep -i network
10:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)

# rpm -qa | fgrep -i broadcom-wl
broadcom-wl-5.100.82.38-1.fc14.noarch

# lsmod | fgrep -i br
#

# ifconfig -a
eth0 ...
lo ...
# 

# uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.35.13-92.fc14.i686 #1 SMP Sat May 21 17:39:42 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

# lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.0-ia32:core-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: Fedora
Description:    Fedora release 14 (Laughlin)
Release:    14
Codename:   Laughlin
# 

# vi /var/log/messages:
Jul 16 14:21:40 localhost NetworkManager[1173]: <info> found WiFi radio killswitch rfkill0 (at /sys/devices/platform/hp-wmi/rfkill/rfkill0) (driver hp-wmi)
Jul 16 14:21:40 localhost NetworkManager[1173]: <info> WiFi disabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Jul 16 14:22:12 localhost NetworkManager[1173]: <info> WiFi now enabled by radio killswitch
Jul 16 14:24:05 localhost NetworkManager[1215]: <info> found WiFi radio killswitch rfkill0 (at /sys/devices/platform/hp-wmi/rfkill/rfkill0) (driver hp-wmi)
Jul 16 14:24:05 localhost NetworkManager[1215]: <info> WiFi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Jul 16 14:24:32 localhost NetworkManager[1215]: <info> WiFi now disabled by radio killswitch
Jul 16 14:24:37 localhost NetworkManager[1215]: <info> WiFi now enabled by radio killswitch
#
```

Comment: Does the `dmesg` results say something about the kernel module for the broadcom drivers? Are the .o files where they should be? Did you had a recent kernel update? (I'm running Fedora 15, I don't keep up with F14 anymore).

Comment: You could also try to reinstall `akmod-wl`. `broadcom-wl` is the common package, with `kmod-wl` and `akmod-wl` being the driver version in itself. Does it match your kernel version?

Comment: it's funny, because I have two identical laptops with the same up-to-date version of Fedora14, and the problem occurs only on one of them. thx for the tip, i will try

Comment: If one of the laptops is using `akmod-wl` (the auto updating version of the driver) and the other is running `kmod-wl` (the version that doesn't update itself) this would explain one working and the other don't after an update.